# Can't create outlets in xcode 6.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm reading the book IOS Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th Edition.
I have come to the section where I should make a outlet connection.

I have the following code:

```
@interface BNRQuizViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;

@end

@implementation BNRQuizViewController

@end
```

In the book it says:
[image]

I only get this in my xcode:
[image: my xcode]

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: you probably missed setting the controller's class (BNRQuizViewController). if I remember correctly you should be able to set that in the identity inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't set the custom class on your xib, in the right sidebar:

[image: Setting the custom class]

However, you should refrain from creating the view controllers and xibs separately, I suggest you use storyboards, or create a xib along with your header and implementation files by selecting the proper checkmark to avoid having xibs with a different name and deattached from your view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What should the custom class be named?

Comment: it should not be "named", you should select your class in which you declared your outlet from the combobox

Comment: If you're asking what to type inside, type the name of your custom class, in this case, BNRQuizViewController.